# Поймать скролл на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() == 400) {
            load();
        }
    });
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как аналогичное сделать на чистом JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `if(this.scrollTop == 400) { alert('test'); }` не работает

Может и не сработать, потому что скролл движется с определённым шагом и ровно 400 пикселей может никогда и не выпасть.

По этому будем проверять на то, "перескочили" ли мы этот предел в 400 пикселей.
Но простое условие `if(scroll > 400)` будет выполняться каждый раз после 400.

Используем для этого булевевое значение и будем его изменять после "перескока".
`if(scroll > 400 && boolean === false) boolean = true;` - после такой проверки скрипт выполниться один раз.

```js
var eScroll = 400,  // После скольки пикселей запустить что-то
    is400px = false; // Чтобы скрипт не срабатывал каждый раз после 400px
    
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  console.clear();
  console.info(this.scrollY);
  
  if(this.scrollY >= eScroll && is400px === false) {
    is400px = true;
    load();
  }
});

function load() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
}
```

```css
body {
  height: calc(500px + 100vh);
}
```

Так же обратите внимание на то, какое число будет указанно в консоли.

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз столкнулась с такой проблемой. На компьютере скролл шел 100, 200, 300 и т.д, а на телефоне ровно 400 не выпадало.

Comment: @ЕленаЛарина, если мой ответ Вам помог - отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте  событие [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)  и свойство [scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (this.scrollY == 400) {
        load();
    }
});
```

Comment: if (this.scrollTop == 400) { alert('test'); } не работает

Comment: Вместо this.scrollTop использовала window.scrollY и все заработало

Comment: @ЕленаЛарина спасибо подправил